# Javascript Regex replace html elements with similar instances

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this string:

```
const text = "1x 15 inch Free Choice Pizza
<br>Tomato Base
<br>Stuffed Crust Cheese, Garlic & Herbs
<br>
Sweetcorn<br>
Onion<br>
Salami<br>
Chicken - 19.68~<br>
2x BBQ Dip - 1.00~<br>2x Meat Lasagne - 12.98~<br>
1x Vanilla Haagen Dazs Ice Cream - 5.99~<br>
1x Strawberry Cheesecake Haagen Dazs Ice Cream - 5.99~<br>
1x Cookies & Cream Haagen Dazs Ice Cream - 5.99~<br>
2x Water - 1.98~"
```

I am using a regex to replace all instances of `<br>` on its own with `xxx<br>` so the `~<br>` preceeded with a tilde `~` should be ignored.

The `-` is replaced with `<span class="float-end">£`

And finally the tilde `~` is replaced with `</span>\n`

The `\n` isn't honoured and if I replace it with `</span><br>` then the first expression replaces it.

```
const replacedText = text
            .replaceAll(/~<br>/g, '</span><br>')
            .replaceAll(/ - /g, '<span class="float-end">£')
            .replaceAll(/<br>(?!~<br>)/g, '<br>xxx');
```

How can I avoid replacing the added `<br>` in the first expression? Or force a new line instead of using `</span><br>` because `</span>\n` doesn't work.

Update: after comment from wiktor using a look behind - I had to reorder the expressions, I am left with the final tilde not being replaced.

```
const replacedText = text
        .replaceAll(/(?<!~)<br>/g, '<br>xxx')
        .replaceAll(/~<br>/g, '</span><br>')
        .replaceAll(/ - /g, '<span class="float-end">£');
```

Comment: Using a lookbehind: `.replaceAll(/(?<!~)<br>/g, '<br>xxx')`

Comment: That gets it much closer I just left with the last `~`.

Comment: Sorted the final ~ didn't have a <br> attached its why. Added a new replace. Thank you @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
const replacedText = text
        .replaceAll(/(?<!~)<br>/g, '<br>xxx')
        .replaceAll(/~<br>/g, '</span><br>')
        .replaceAll(/ - /g, '<span class="float-end">£');
```

where `(?<!~)<br>` matches any `<br>` string not immediately preceded with a tilde.

So, to make it work you need to first replace all those `<br>` that have no tilde before them, and only then replace with those that have a tilde before.